# Java BlueTooth list of remote devices

Tags: java, bluetooth, java-me

I searched all over the web and I cannot find an answer to this simple question: how to display in j2me a list of all bluetooth devices in the neighbourhood?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to choose a bluetooth stack.

You have a choice of [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/) or [Avetana](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/jsr82.eng.xml) (these too I'm aware of).

Then search their documentation for "device discovery".

Comment: You can only use JSR82 in Java ME

Comment: @funkybro - uh.. both libraries I gave are implementations of JSR-82.. so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First, bear in mind that in the emulator you can't detect 'real' Bluetooth devices without a third-party JSR-82 library such as [Bluecove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/) (it's a desktop implementation for Java Bluetooth). But when you deploy to a JSR-82 capable phone, it should work.

But otherwise, it's easy with JSR-82! You can use the DiscoveryAgent class.

```
LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();  
DiscoveryAgent agent = local.getDiscoveryAgent();
boolean complete = agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, new DiscoveryListener() {
   public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice device, DeviceClass cod) {
      System.out.println("Discovered: " + device.getFriendlyName());    } 
});
while(!complete) {
    // wait until discovery completes before continuing 
}
```

Instead of printing the discovered devices as above, you could always put them into the Hashtable or Vector. The deviceDiscovered() method gets called everytime a device is discovered whilst the inquiry is running, and the inquiry usually returns in a decent time (a matter of 10s of seconds).

Comment: This is wrong. The call to startInquiry does not block, or return a second boolean value when it finishes. This code will sit and spin in the while loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
DiscoveryAgent agent = local.getDiscoveryAgent();
// use inquiryStarted to make sure two inquiries aren't running at the same
// time.
inquiryStarted = agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC,
        new DiscoveryListener() {
            public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice device,
                    DeviceClass cod) {
                System.out.println("Discovered: "
                        + device.getFriendlyName());
            }
                @Override
            public void inquiryCompleted(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void serviceSearchCompleted(int arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void servicesDiscovered(int arg0,
                        ServiceRecord[] arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```